# Creating of a dynamic iframe with a jquery click event

Tags: jquery, events, iframe, dynamic, click

When I create an iframe dynamically like this

```
$( '<iframe/>' )
    .attr('id', 'aaoifr0')
    .attr('src', aPageName)
    .appendTo(_public.content);
```

and add a click event to the `body` element in the iframe

```
$('#aaoifr0')
    .contents().find('body').click(function(){ alert(0) });
```

it does not work.

However, if I add the event manually after the iframe is displayed, via firebug, like this:

```
$('#aaoifr0').contents().find('body').click(function(){ alert(0) });
```

it works fine!

I've tried several ways to check the load sync/async of the iframe content but couldn't find a useful answer. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: After a few debugs more I have the feeling that the problem is in the assignment of the click event... It seems to stay in the parent page and not in the html of the iframe... ?may this be a jquery 'confusing' thing???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved it..

The solution is to use the `.load()` method of the JQuery created frame object.

**Attention:** don't use `.ready()`, it will refer to the parent document. You can test it in the following way:

```
$('<iframe/>')
  .attr('id', 'someId')
  .attr('src', 'aPageSrc')
  .appendTo(_public.content)
  .load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').click(function() {
      alert('Loaded!');
    });
  })
  .ready(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').click(function() {
      alert('Ready!');
    });
  });
```

This was hard to figure, I hope next ones be a lot easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('<iframe id="aaoifr0" src="' + aPageName  + '"></iframe>')
```

also when you append jquery objects you need to append to another jquery object, not the content of object, _public.content might be an issue there depend on what object is it.  safer to try

```
$('<iframe id="aaoifr0" src="' + aPageName  + '"></iframe>').appendto( $('document.body') );
```

I think with iframe i had an issue add

```
<iframe />
```

you need

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

also jquery can only access iframe content if the iframe src is from the same domain.  but since firebug works, it shouldn't be an issue

not sure if that helps, let me know if there are other problem.

Comment: The problem is in the add of the click event... all the rest work well... 
also "_public.content" is a jquery object, more specifically a div... like this : _public.content=$("#divContent")

Comment: is the iframe src in the same domain as the page running the script?

Comment: Yes, is in a sub folder... again I emphasize that after the page is loaded in the browser applying the same code to the div that holds the content via Firebug, which is in a jquery object, WORKS fine...

$('#aaoifr0').contents().find('body').click( function(){ alert(0) } );

that leads me to think that i am missing something that is happening in the event plumbing between the page and the iframe...
?anyone has an idea...